# Deleting annoying system sounds in Catalina

Tags: audio, root

I loathe the sounds made when dropping a file into a folder. So for years I've deleted:

System /Library /Components /CoreAudio.component (Show Package Contents) /SharedSupport /SystemSounds /system

/Volume Mount.aif [and]
/Volume Unmount.aif

I'd replace them with silent files I'd created bearing the same filenames. But now, Catalina prevents me from deleting them. Although the following article's method allowed me to change the permissions on the files (and their enclosing folder)…

[MacOS switched root Mongodb data folder to system ownership and it cannot be changed back anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/1458974/macos-switched-root-mongodb-data-folder-to-system-ownership-and-it-cannot-be-cha/1459064#1459064)

…Catalina still just ignores the commands. (WTF, Apple? All I want to do is delete a couple of .aif audio files. What's the big frigging deal?)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i hope this can help you out: https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/mac-help/mchlp2207/mac

1. Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Sound, then click Sound Effects.
2. To select an alert sound, click it in the list.
   The alert plays when you select it so you can hear how it sounds.
3. Choose whether to hear user interface sound effects: Your Mac plays sound effects when you perform certain actions, such as dragging an item to the Trash. To turn off sound effects, deselect the “Play user interface sound effects” tickbox.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the suggestion, but no, that's something different. 